# Is it possible to check if Google Chrome is installed on a client's computer?

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-chrome

I have a web project created in VS 2008 with VB.NET

The mininum browser we are planning to support is IE8 or above.  We would like to be able to automatically detect if Google Chrome is installed on a client's machine, and if not, point to the website for installation.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Your browser is pretty much a sandbox.

The only way to know if someone has Chrome is for them to visit it inside Chrome.

Comment: As well it should be, thank you very much. I don't want those grubby, nefarious web designers getting their hands on my computer's innards!

Comment: I was wondering how itunes.com detects if iTunes is installed on a computer or no. If you visit the iTunes Website (like this for example... https://itunes.apple.com/ae/artist/lorde/id602767352) and click on the 'View in iTunes' button, iTunes opens if it was installed, but if iTunes is not installed on the client computer, they redirect you to download iTunes. I wonder how this was done... @CodyGray

Comment: @DanielA.White well registering a URL handler will allow them to invoke iTunes, but how do they detect if iTunes is present?

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel mentions, you can't get at the other programs installed on the computer from a web application running inside of a browser, so there's no way to tell whether they *also* have Chrome or Firefox or Mosaic installed on their computer if they don't use it to visit your web page.

But this is really no matter. In fact, I don't understand what detecting Google Chrome has to do with the decision that was made to only support IE 8 and above. All you need to do is detect whether or not the user's current browser is supported or unsupported.

If it's unsupported, display a message informing them of that and offering a link to download a supported browser. Chrome can be among your suggested browsers if you like it, but you should also offer a link to IE 8 in case the customer is already comfortable with IE and would prefer to continue using it.

The only people whom this approach *doesn't* catch are those who have alternative, supported browsers installed on their computers, but chose to visit your page using one of the unsupported ones. Since the users that tend to have multiple web browsers installed are those that know what's up, this should not really be an issue. In the off chance that you *do* get someone who has multiple browsers installed but doesn't know it, the worst thing that can happen is she visits your page from IE 7, gets an error, and follows your instructions to download Chrome. And then you can just let the Chrome installer handle the case where the user is trying to install on top of an existing application. Not only is it always better to let someone else solve your problem, but it has access to the necessary system information it needs, something you don't have access to from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the BrowserCapabilities class in ASP.NET? When writing server controls, you can read information about the browser to allow rendering to specific browsers. I dont know if you can find enough clues to tell whether it is chrome, but you might be able to figure it out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx

Answer (score -1):

What about  checking for folder and exe:

If file.Exist("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")...

Comment: What if user has customised install? Also, browsers don't allow to check if a file exists in system.